# Read files from client's PC with JS without uploading

Tags: javascript, file

I am making a website to manage and save all my contacts online... To add a new contact in the database I have to type the full contact in my website like filling up a form. But believe me or not, I have 3,000+ contacts to save. So I am trying to make my work easier.

I have created an HTML drop box in my website to drop the vCards. Now I don't want to upload them to my server and use PHP to read the file contents and parse the information (name, mobile number, emails etc) from the vCard, because in my country the internet connection is not good at all. I get only 30-56 kbps for browsing. Rather I'd like to be able to do that with javascript without uploading them. On the one hand I don't have to upload the whole file. On the other hand, PHP won't have to do anything before I save it in the database.

I have the dropped files' location from the HTML drop box. Now I need to load the files one by one and read their contents as strings in Javascript. And I know how to do the rest.

Does anyone know how I can do that? No jQuery please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) which is present on [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).